# Profiling Wicket applications

Tags: profiling, wicket

Are there any good tools or techniques to profile Wicket applications? What I'm looking for is something that would give me a breakdown of what's happening inside Wicket while processing a request.

It doesn't have to be as fancy as Spring insight.

I'm new to Wicket and all the anonymous inner classes spread around everywhere makes it very hard to see when things are happening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least for Wicket 1.4 one can take a look at the internal method `org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps()`. Basically, this is the place where a request that has been identified as a request to the Wicket application is walked through the relevant steps of the Wicket request processing cycle. In the beginning of the class `RequestCycle`, the main steps are represented each by an int constant. The higher the int value, the later the step comes within the cycle. The method `RequestCycle.step()` that gets called from `RequestCycle.steps()` has a switch statement to delegate the different steps to the responsible framework methods which delegate further down.

The steps, or phases if you like, in the request cycle are in order:

- NOT_STARTED - initial value
- PREPARE_REQUEST - preparation for further processing, calls onBeginRequest
- RESOLVE_TARGET - determine the relevant request target
- PROCESS_EVENTS - process events, set current step to RESPOND and respond as well
- RESPOND - only respond, used in case of redirects
- DETACH_REQUEST - trigger the detach hooks by delegation
- DONE - becomes the current value after DETACH_REQUEST

What is actually happening inside the steps is determined by the implementations of various interfaces, most notably `IRequestCycleProcessor` and `IRequestTarget`.

Comment: Thanks! This provided me with new insight into Wicket

Answer (score 6):

See

org.apache.wicket.response.filter.ServerAndClientTimeFilter
org.apache.wicket.response.filter.AjaxServerAndClientTimeFilter
org.apache.wicket.devutils.inspector.RenderPerformanceListener
org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.RequestLogger

All these give some measurements but also see my comment of Cedric Gatay's response.
Using tools like Yourkit (http://www.yourkit.com) will help you a lot for this task.

Answer (score 1):

You can profile using jvisualvm like any other Java application. With a correct class filter set you will be able to see what is time consuming in your code and hopefully correct it.

Comment: That sorta works, but doesn't really offer any proper insight into the order of things (which is far from obvious in Wicket applications) and the interaction with the framework.

Comment: Do you want to profile Wicket itself or your app ? By adding such points in Wicket you will see something like: submitting a form took X ms, clicking a link took Y ms, rendering took Z ms, ... But this information wont be sufficient. The only thing you can say is that clicking a link is slow, but this wont tell you that #onClick() impl hits a DB or a WebService and this is the real perf problem.

Comment: The ideal solution would give insight into Wicket and my application and how they interact. The Wicket filters looks like a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I found that `wicket-devutils` ships with a panel called `DebugBar` that provides access to a lot of debug information.

It can be seen in action here: http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/devutils/debugbar/DebugBar.html